# MySQL data comparison

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL table containing data for over 1500 online games. Each of those games have tags describing them (between 1 to 5 tags for each game). For example, [this game](http://www.solidgames.com/solid-rider.html) has the following tags "Dirt Bike", "Racing", "Stunts", "Trial", "Mountain" in ORDER OF IMPORTANCE. For each of those games I'd like to select the most related 12 games.

I was thinking about giving an "order of importance" weight to each tag.

Tag 1 = 5 pts

Tag 2 = 4 pts

Tag 3 = 3 pts

Tag 4 = 2 pts

Tag 5 = 1 pt

And multiply the matching tags. So if another game is about "Car", "Racing", "Mountain", it would get: 0 + (4 x 4) + (3 x 1) = 19pts. I would then compare the results of all games and show the 12 with the most points.

I know how to code the mathematical comparison part using PHP but don't know how to efficiently store the partial results (ie, the comparison points for each 1500) before showing only the top 12 games. Should I create a table to store the temporary 1500 results? Or is there a way to store those results in memory and then grab only the top 12?

Note: I'll probably store the final results in a 1500x12 SQL table and run the comparison only when I'll add new games, about once a day.

Comment: Interesting! That is a very cool idea! +1

Comment: This question is a bit broad at the moment - it's an interesting question but it probably isn't a good fit for here. You certainly _can_ do this with PHP, but it's probably better if you give it a go, and then ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: What's your question? Please describe the part you have problems with.

Comment: How is the data accessible?

Comment: You should not store the weight (or points) in the database. Instead, you should develop your query(ies) with the live data - possibly conditional queries. Reason being is the tags may change (add/edit/delete) and then your pivot tables would become obsolete. You may also want to try and write a PHP library that handles this.

Answer (score 2):

While the question should be regarded as too broad to be a good fit here (please try something before asking!), it is funny enough forto me to answer it.

I wouldn't do this in PHP, but in pure SQL.

Assuming a structure like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE game (
    game_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE tag (
    tag_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    label VARCHAR (50)
);

CREATE TABLE gametag (
    game_id INT,
    tag_id INT,
    rank INT, -- ranks from 1 to 5, rank "1" will weightmeans "5 points"
    PRIMARY KEY (game_id, tag_id),
    UNIQUE (game_id, tag_id, rank),
    CONSTRAINT gid_fk FOREIGN KEY gid_fk_idx (game_id) REFERENCES game (game_id),
    CONSTRAINT tid_fk FOREIGN KEY tid_fk_idx (tag_id) REFERENCES tag (tag_id)
);
```

The "matching score" between two games would be obtained with a query like this:

```sql
SELECT
    game1.name AS game_1,
    game2.name AS game_2,
    SUM(match_score) AS score
FROM (
    SELECT
        game1.game_id AS game1_id,
        game2.game_id AS game2_id,
        (6 - gametag1.rank) * (6 - gametag2.rank) AS match_score -- modify the magic "6" if you allow more or less than 5 tags
    FROM game AS game1
    JOIN gametag AS gametag1 USING (game_id)
    JOIN tag AS tag1 USING (tag_id)
    JOIN tag AS tag2 USING (tag_id)
    JOIN gametag AS gametag2 USING (tag_id)
    JOIN game AS game2 ON game2.game_id = gametag2.game_id
    WHERE game1.game_id = 1 AND game2.game_id = 2
) AS scores
JOIN game AS game1 ON game1.game_id = game1_id
JOIN game AS game2 ON game2.game_id = game2_id
GROUP BY game1_id, game2_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres some SQL, maybe this would work?:

```
SELECT g.id AS game_id, g.game AS game_name, SUM(t.tag_points) AS tag_points 
FROM games g
INNER JOIN game_tags gt 
    ON gt.game_id = g.id 
INNER JOIN tags t
    ON t.id = gt.tag_id
GROUP BY gt.game_id  
ORDER BY tag_points DESC
```

You would need a table structure similar to this:

```
Table: games
+----+-------------+
| id | game        |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | Test Game 1 |
| 2  | Test Game 2 |
+----+-------------+

 Table: tags
+----+------------+------------+
| id | tag_name   | tag_points |
+----+------------+------------+
| 1  | test tag 1 | 1          |
| 2  | test tag 2 | 2          |
+----+------------+------------+

Table: game_tags
+----+---------+--------+
| id | game_id | tag_id |
+----+---------+--------+
| 1  | 1       | 1      |
| 2  | 2       | 1      |
| 3  | 2       | 2      |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

table `tags`

```
id  |    name    |
------------------
 1  |    cars    |
 2  |    rpg     |
 3  |   shooter  |
 4  |  mountain  |
 5  |    fps     |
 6  |   trial    |
 7  |   racing   |
 8  |   ....     |
 9  |   ....     |
```

table `games`

```
id  |    name    |
------------------
 1  | race_game  |
 2  | shoot_game |
```

table `game_tags`

```
id  | game_id | first_tag | second_tag | third_tag | fourth_tag | fifth_tag | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   1     |    7      |     1      |     4     |       2    |    6      |
2   |   2     |    5      |     8      |     3     |       2    |    9      |
```

SO you can LEFT JOIN the game_tags multiple time to compare where tags from the first join are equal to the second join and so on. The LEFT JOIN would give you NULL results on non matching values, so only the matchable will have the tag_id. Depending on which tag the match is, you can give the points. For example if the match here starts from the fourth tag, you will give the points for fourth_tag, as I understand, first_tag matches gives more points, and decreases with the rank of the tag.